# How to keep certain regions of code in powerdesigner?

Tags: powerdesigner

I have an OOM model with a few classes that will be transformed into C++ code.

I want certain sections (ie. custom `#include`s in .cpp files) to remain untouched when I re-generate the code from the model. However if I modify the model and generate the code again this defines & includes are lost.

Found nothing looking at the [docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38628.1600/doc/html/rad1232022541017.html) for macros or variables that may be of help.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Script` tab of a class property sheet, there is a `Imports` subtab. Looking in the Object Language Definition, this attribute does not seem to be used anywhere.

I managed to use it by editing the `Profile\Class\Templates\Source\includes_cpp` template in the Language definition, adding `%Imports%` at the end.

After that, this `Imports` appears in the generated source:

```
#include "Class_2.h"
#include "Class_1.h"
MY INCLUDES
```